# Something wrong with values in submit buttons

Tags: zend-framework, button, submit, zend-form

```
    $button = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('melnraksts');
    $button->setAttrib('id','melnraksts');
    $button->setValue(Lang::$form[17]);
    $button->setDecorators(array('Composite')); 
    $button->removeDecorator('Errors');     
    $form->addElement($button);

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id','submit');
    $submit->setValue(Lang::$form['1']);
    $submit->setDecorators(array('Composite')); 
    $submit->removeDecorator('Errors');     
    $form->addElement($submit);
```

[image]

Don't know why one of the submit buttons value dissapear after validation triggers.

Left button is disabled via javascript, by returning false.

So why does it's value dissapear? O_o

Maybe because they both have submit type? Maybe there is another way to make submit type button?

Comment: If you put a string in the setValue calls, does it display anything? What about removing the second element?

Comment: I need if for the form draft. Form draft is written on javascript.
So this second button is only for this purpose. But it should look the same as input type=submit. Is there any way to create <button> element next to submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$submit->setLabel('My label')`